# Resizing different type of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, actionscript-2

I'm searching a JavaScript method to resize and fill in a block with a fixed width some different images with different types of width and height.

I've found actually something looking familiar but it's in AS2 I don't know if it can be conversed in JavaScript.

```
var _loc3 = _caseWidth * 100 / caseItem.item._width;
var _loc2 = _caseHeight * 100 / caseItem.item._height;
caseItem._xscale = caseItem._yscale = _loc3 > _loc2 ? (_loc2) : (_loc3);
caseItem.item._x = -caseItem.item.getBounds(caseItem).xMin + (_caseWidth - caseItem._width) / 2;
caseItem.item._y = -caseItem.item.getBounds(caseItem).yMin;
```

Comment: How about some simple CSS: `object-fit: cover` or `object-fit: contain` ?

Comment: css cover is better than javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to use `object-fit: cover` with CSS. You will avoid unnecessary javascript loads